# Configure HP RAID in Pre-OS environment

Tags: windows, deployment, hp-proliant, provisioning, windows-pe

I need to set the RAID configurations of a HP machine during the provisioning process of OS deployment. I have come across a tool named Praid.exe but having read the documentation I get the impression it is only usable on IBM RAID configurations.

Has anyone set the RAID configurationsfor a HP device during provisioning? or does anyone know of a tool that may offer the ability to do so?

I am using WinPE environment post-OS.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HP provides the [Array Configuration Utility](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/), which contains a CLI component you can use to configure the RAID devices.  You would need to bundle these tools into your WinPE WIM or make them available via a network share.

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the RAID controller firmware. The newest revisions add access to the hpacucli command line utility during the BIOS screen. Otherwise, you could automate your SmartStart installs. Look for the `conrep` utility.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on an HP Proliant server ?

If so, just pop in the SmartStart CD/DVD and go.

"HP machine" is uselessly vague.

Comment: This is part of an imaging process so the idea is to have the process unattended and without the need to pop in a CD/DVD.

Comment: So insert the SmartStart CD and install/copy the components you need to your image.

Comment: Interesting idea...